# How to authenticate to BigQuery using the Google Cloud SDK and API Keys

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I can find lots of resources that tell me how to authenticate with Google Cloud services using a key file... but if I can't use files (long story, don't ask) how can I use the Google Cloud SDK to authenticate with an API Key?

I have generated an API Key in the Console's "APIs & Services" section but can't find any code examples showing how to use these with Google's BigQuery service for example:

```
// This is from the samples - but how can I pass in the API key instead??
const storage = new Storage({projectId, keyFilename});
```

Comment: Please keep in mind, that you can use or inline the file if you don't have access to some weird file restriction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BigQuery does not support API Key authorization. You must use an OAuth 2.0 Access Token. Nothing else is supported.

If your code is running in Google Cloud, you can use the service account assigned to the service. This method does not require a **secrets** file.

If your code is running outside of Google Cloud, you will need to use a service account JSON key file OR use user credentials OR user credentials that impersonate a service account. Each of these methods requires a **secrets** file.

**[UPDATE 2021-20-17]**

Based upon the comment below the OP is coding in JavaScript and deploying on Cloudflare Workers.

The Google Cloud Node.js Auth library supports loading service account JSON key material from an environment variable. This link provides example code:

[Loading credentials from environment variables](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#loading-credentials-from-environment-variables)

Cloudflare Workers support storing configuration data via wrangler. The Cloudflare Dashboard supports adding environment variables. This link provides details on Cloudflare Environment Variables:

[Adding environment variables via wrangler](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/platform/environment-variables)

Given that a service account JSON key material are **secrets**, I recommend using **wrangler secrets** instead of environment variables. Secrets are added using the CLI: **wrangler secret put**. The secret can then be accessed in JavaScript as an environment variable.

[Adding secrets via wrangler](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/platform/environment-variables#adding-secrets-via-wrangler)

[Wrangler Secret Put](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/cli-wrangler/commands#secret)

Comment: Thanks, so it's not possible to use the Google SDK from a service like CloudFlare Workers were filesystem access is not supported?

Comment: @ConfusedNoob Yes, you can use the Google Cloud JavaScript SDK from CloudFlare Workers. The key is to load your service account credentials from an environment variable. JS example: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#loading-credentials-from-environment-variables CloudFlare environment variables: https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/platform/environment-variables

Comment: One thing that's not super clear - how do you use this with a client SDK like BigQuery? Do I pass in the client object? If so, how?

Comment: I worked it out: 

new BigQuery({ projectId: "project-id", credentials: keys }) 

Where 'keys' is the keys object in the sample above.

Answer (score -1):

You can use application default credentials for the local development and testing for Prod needs to use a service account with appropriate permissions